# React Router Rendering all Components Together Instead of Rendering one at a Time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css, react-router-dom

I am trying to render two different components, one at a time using a single page. I want just the home to show with the `LatestArticles` component when the app loads and the article page to only load with the `FullArticle` component when a post is clicked from the home page.
But instead, `react-router` is rendering the `Home` page with the `LatestArticles` component and the `FullArticle` component together. Please I need help loading just the home page with the `LatestArticles` component and the `Articles` Page with just the `FullArticles` component, and not the two components loading all together in the home page, which makes the page look horrible.

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './pages/Home';
import Article from './pages/Article';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="sm:w-[97%] block mx-auto sm:shadow-md">
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/article" element={<Article />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Home page

```
import React from 'react';
import Header from '../components/Header';
import Slides from '../components/Slides';
import PagingSetup from '../components/PagingSetup';
import Footer from '../components/Footer';
import ScrollUpButton from '../components/ScrollUpButton';

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <Slides />
      <PagingSetup />
      <Footer />
      <ScrollUpButton />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Article page

```
import React from 'react';
import Header from '../components/Header';
import Footer from '../components/Footer';
import PagingSetup from '../components/PagingSetup';
import ScrollUpButton from '../components/ScrollUpButton';

const Article = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <Header />
        <PagingSetup />
        <Footer />
        <ScrollUpButton />
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Article;
```

Single page that contains the two components

```
import React from 'react';
import LatestArticles from './LatestArticles';
import all_posts from '../pages/all_posts';
import Bio from './Bio';
import Tags from './Tags';
import FullArticle from './FullArticle';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const PagingSetup = () => {
  // Filter all post with type of latest
  const type = 'Latest';
  const latest = all_posts.filter((latestPost) => latestPost.type === type);
  const body = all_posts.map((post, index) => post);

  return (
    <>
      <section className="lg:py-5 py-1 contentpage max-w-[96%]">
        <div className="container w-[100%] mx-auto">
          <div className="flex lg:flex-row flex-col py-1">
            
            {/* Import Different Post Component Here */}
            <Link to="/" className="flex lg:basis-2/3 basis-full">
              <LatestArticles latestPost={latest} />
            </Link>
            <Link to="/article" className="flex lg:basis-2/3 basis-full">
              <FullArticle articleBody={body} />
            </Link>
</div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </>
  );
};

export default PagingSetup;
```

Latest article component

```
import React from 'react';
import { MdOutlineShare } from 'react-icons/md';
import { FaRegComment } from 'react-icons/fa';
import { BsHandThumbsUp } from 'react-icons/bs';

const latestPost = (props) => {
  const { latestPost } = props;

  return (
    <>
      <div className="grid grid-cols-2 gap-4">
        <div className="col-span-2">
          <h2 className="text-[2rem] font-medium leading-[1.2]">Latest Post</h2>
        </div>
        {latestPost.map((latest) => (
          <div
            key={latest.id}
            className="border-blue-700 rounded-lg overflow-hidden shadow-md"
          >
            <a href="£">
              <img
                className="object-cover object-center rounded-t-md"
                src={latest.backgroundImage}
                alt="latest"
              />
              <div className="lg:text-lg leading-[1.5] font-bold lg:px-4 px-2 py-1 text-justify">
                <h2>{latest.title}</h2>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default latestPost;
```

Full article component

```
import React from 'react';

const FullArticle = (props) => {
  const { articleBody } = props;
  return (
    <>
      <div className="flex flex-col">
        <img
          src={articleBody.backgroundImage}
          alt="post pix"
          className="mb-12 max-w-[100%] h-auto align-middle border-none object-cover"
        />
        <h1 className="mb-6 text-[#000] sm:text-[2.5rem] text-2xl font-medium leading-tight mt-0">
          {articleBody.title}
        </h1>
        <div>
          <p className="mt-0 mb-4 font-light sm:text-lg text-sm leading-[1.9] text-[#6c757d] text-justify">
            {articleBody.content}
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default FullArticle;
```

What did I do wrong that the two components are rendering all together?

Comment: I see no issue with your code at all, and in fact, it works as expected here in this running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-rendering-all-components-together-instead-of-rendering-one-at-a-tim-86xx95). Can you fork this sandbox and add more of your actual code to see if you can reproduce the issue and share a link to it back to us to inspect live?

Comment: Sorry, after another read through I see now the issue you have is specifically in the `PagingSetup` where you are rendering `LatestArticles` and `FullArticle` ***as*** the link components. `all_posts` is an array, are you rendering multiple duplicate links? It sounds like you want these different article views rendered somewhere in the routes you are linking to though, but it's unclear what UI/UX you are trying to accomplish here overall. Can you [edit] to clarify what you are wanting the UI and routes to do?

Answer (score -1):

> This is the Single page that contains the two components

What you are doing in this page is not how React Router is supposed to work, that is why it is not working as expected.

> But instead, react-router is rendering the Home page with the LatestArticles component and the FullArticle component together.

React is doing this because that is what you are ordering it to do.

Here are two possible solutions that would work.

1. **Calling the final component directly**

Article:

```
const Article = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <Header />
        <LatestArticles />
        <Footer />
        <ScrollUpButton />
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Article;
```

Home:

```
const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <Slides />
      <FullArticle />
      <Footer />
      <ScrollUpButton />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

2. **Passing trough props which components we want to show**

Another approach that would make less changes to your current project would be passing a prop to PagingSetup so this component can know if you want to show *LatestArticles* or *FullArticle*.

This solution would look like this:

```
const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <Slides />
      <PagingSetup isHome={true} />
      <Footer />
      <ScrollUpButton />
    </div>
  );
};

const Article = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <Slides />
      <PagingSetup isHome={false} />
      <Footer />
      <ScrollUpButton />
    </div>
  );
};
```

And PagingSetup would be:

```
{ props.isHome ?
<LatestArticles latestPost={latest} />
:
<FullArticle articleBody={body} />
}
```

This code shows LatestArticles when isHome is true, and FullArticle when isHome is false.